# Old capitalization shown in Help Center screenshot of 10k privileges

Tags: bug, user-interface, top-bar, help-center, privileges-page

Currently the [10k privilege page in the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) has a screenshot of review queues dropdown of the top-bar that shows "All queues" and "Tools" written in lower case while it's currently in upper case in the UI. The color of the icons has also changed in the meanwhile.

[image: screenshot of review queues drop-down list in top-bar]

Comment: Are there any other updates that need to be made to that help page?

Comment: @V2Blast I think the edit tags screenshot has also a new style without the surrounding box (should I post it separately or edit this post)? I also think in the paragraph that says: *"you also get a full history of actions taken by others in /review by clicking the history tab in any queue"* there should be a [direct link to an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) because it took me a couple of weeks to figure out where the mentioned tab actually was (and you know how it goes, asking a potential duplicate question to find out isn't a good idea)...